# beginner haskell programmer

Tags: haskell

```
isPalindrome::(Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome [] = True
isPalindrome [x] = True
isPalindrome (x1:xs:x2:[]) 
    | x1 == x2 = isPalindrome xs
    |otherwise = False


[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( myHas.hs, interpreted )

myHas.hs:37:27:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a]' against inferred type `a1'
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for `isPalindrome' at myHas.hs:33:18
    In the first argument of `isPalindrome', namely `xs'
    In the expression: isPalindrome xs
    In the definition of `isPalindrome':
        isPalindrome (x1 : xs : x2 : [])
                       | x1 == x2 = isPalindrome xs
                       | otherwise = False
```

I'm a beginner haskell programmer and got no clue as to why I'm getting this error, any help please?

Answer (score 13):

You treat `xs` like a list, but `(x1:xs:x2:[])` assumes it is an element of your input list.

Note that `(x1:xs:x2:[])` will match only lists with 3 elements, and `x1`, `xs` and `x2` will be elements of type `a`.

So `xs` is of type `a`, but as you pass it to `isPalindrome`, we can only assume it must be a list of something, so the type system calls the type `[a1]`.

The easiest way to encode what you want is:

```haskell
isPalindrome::(Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome l = l == (reverse l)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an easy to understand answer, similar to your attempt:

```
isPalindrome [] = True
isPalindrome [x] = True
isPalindrome xs = (head xs == last xs) && isPalindrome (init (tail xs))
```

So an empty or one-element list is a palindrome, and a longer list is an palindrome if the first and last element are equal, and the elements "in the middle" are a palindrome as well.

Note that MGwynne's answer is **much** more performant, as the solution above has to traverse the list in every step.

Comment: +1 for giving an answer similar to the question, and then explaining why not to use it!

Answer (score 5):

I feel that an explanation of the syntax used for lists is needed here, which hasn't been given so far. firstly, the definition of the list type in Haskell is:

```
data [a] = a : [a] | []
```

Which says that a list is either empty (`[]`) or it is made from the (`:`) constructor, which has as its left argument an `a`, and another list (the `[a]` in the definition). This means that the list `[1,2,3]` is actually `1 : (2 : (3 : []))`, but this can also be written as just `1 : 2 : 3 : []`.

When pattern matching on a list, you're matching on these constructors:

```
f [] = … -- match the empty list

f (x:[]) = … -- match a list with one element, which you name x

f (x:xs) = … -- match the first element of the list, and whatever the rest of 
             -- the list is, but it must have at least one element. if you call
             -- f [1,2,3], x will be bound to 1, and xs will be bound to [2,3]
             -- because [1,2,3] is the same as (1:[2,3])

f (x:y:xs) = … -- matches a list with at least two elements, which you 
               -- call x and y respectively

f (xs:ys:zs:things) = … -- matches a list with at least three elements,
                        -- which you name, xs, ys and zs.
```

So from this, hopefully it's now clear that

```
f (x1:xs:x2:[])
```

matches a list with exactly three elements, which you name x1, xs and x2.

I hope that helps.